# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception

Tags: java

Can anyone help with a homework problem I am doing? Basically the program I am trying to create asks the user for an integer `N` and then for two separate sets of N integers, these sets are stored in two separate arrays (x and y), and then a function `mixReverse(a, b)` is called with `x` and `y` as the parameters. The `mixReverse(x,y)` function reverses the order of the elements in the y array, and then interleaves the elements of each array into one final array so that the `finalArray` consists of arr1[0], arr2[arr2.length-1], arr1[1], arr2[arr2.length-2], ... arr1[arr1.length-1], arr2[0].

I am have tried this code, but it's problematic:

```
finalArray[0] = arr1[0];
    finalArray[1] = arr1[0];
    for (int j=2; j<(2*arr1.length); j++) {
        if (j%2==0) {
            finalArray[j] = arr1[j/2];
        }

        else {
            finalArray[j] = arr2[(((j+1)*(2))-1)];
        }
    }
```

Specifically this line:          `finalArray[j] = arr1[j/2];`

is throwing the error:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
>       at lab2part1.mixReverse(lab2part1.java:33)
>       at lab2part1.main(lab2part1.java:15)

I know that the error is "Thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal index. The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the size of the array." but I cant figure out why the index is illegal. Then length of the array is 2*(arr1.length), so this for loop should work properly. J is never negative and never equal to anything more than arr1.length -1 (which is equal to the final index of finalArray). Can anyone assist me in finding a solution?

Comment: What was the input on the above failure?

Comment: Where is `finalArray` initialized?

Comment: "Then length of the array is 2*(arr1.length)". The length of which array? Are you sure about the line of the error? Are you sure about the length of each array? Where is the code that sets up the arrays? Have you tried using a debugger? Have you tried using output statements (`System.out.println` or similar) to verify that things are as you think they are at various points in the execution? Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: Changing the snippet into a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem would be really helpful...

Comment: Can you show the definition of `finalArray`? Maybe you're accidentially creating it too small.

Comment: j goes up to 2*arr1.length but finalArray's length is arr1.length ... so maybe that's why you're getting indexOufofBoundsException at this line: finalArray[j] = arr1[j/2]

Comment: @bytebiscuit `but finalArray's length is arr1.length` - where did you get that from?

Comment: Something doesn't make sense here. The line that you quote will never run if `j == 7`, so it must be complaining about `arr1[j/2]` (with `j == 14`); but, if `j < 2 * arr1.length`, then `j / 2 < arr1.length`, so that can't happen. Is it possible that you're running a previously-compiled copy of the code, rather than your current code? Or is it possible that the exception isn't on the line that you think it's on?

Comment: that was just an assumption... but yeah you're right we need the definition of finalArray

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do it this way (without the unreadable mess of %2 and if statements)

```
int[] finalArray = new int[ 2 * N ];

for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ){

    finalArray[ 2 * i ] = array1[ i ];
    finalArray[ 2 * i + 1 ] = array2[ array2.length - i - 1 ];

}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is much cleaner, and I had not even thought about doing it this way.

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
finalArray[j] = arr2[(((j+1)*(2))-1)];
```

Looks suspect. You are using items 7,11,15, e.t.c. of arr2 which I don't think is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If arr1 has the same length of arr2, then this part is the problem:

```
arr2[(((j+1)*(2))-1)];
```

But scibuff has already written a good answer.